# I want to count monthly the reboot of my server pool of 1,000 servers

Tags: count

I want to count monthly the reboot of my server pool of 1,000 servers. Can anyone point me to a product or suggest how I would accomplish this monthly count. A portion of my servers run under MS operating system and about half under Linux. Jim4522

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit? Are you looking to count the number of times each system reboots? Or count how long a reboot takes? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 2):

What centralised management tools do you already have? SCOM will tell you for Windows and a syslog server will tell you for Linux but most centralised management tools will allow for you to script a report such as this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using monitoring software and then there are probably ways to get those reports (at least if it something open and not 100% GUI (Unless the GUI Provides the functionality)).  Do you use something like that?

Heck, if you get email alerts, you could just make an outlook filter (If an unreachable alert is close enough to a reboot for you). :-P

Answer (score 1):

Are those intentional or unintentional reboots? Perhaps you could set up a script to run on system boot and email you when the server reboots? Have it mailed to  `youraddress+reboot@domain.com` for easy filtering into a separate mailbox?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best answer is to use the tool you are already using to monitor your servers. If you don't yet have one, do that first, then ask yourself the same question.

However, a single-use approach would be to run `nmap -O` against all servers to use TCP's timestamp fingerprinting feature: http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-methods.html#osdetect-ts. Run hourly and you probably won't miss too many reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that this is easily met through SNMP traps. Set up your monitoring system (with 1,000 servers you MUST have a monitoring system) to log reboots (or better yet, all traps) into a database, from which you can extract and manipulate the data in any way you see fit. The beauty of storing the traps in a database is that you can run all kinds of queries against it and generate any reports you want.